# How to set the maximum count of chars in a telerik TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox 
    Style="{StaticResource someStyle}" 
    WatermarkContent="{ext:LocalizedText Key=someKey}" 
    SearchText="{Binding SearchTextBox, Mode=TwoWay}"
    TextSearchMode="Contains" IsTabStop="False" Height="34">

    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding someCommand}"/>
    </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox.InputBindings>
</telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
```

I tried `MaxLength` but apparently there is no such property supported.

Comment: Do you mean "maximum number of characters allowed" in the textbox?

Comment: Yes, it was "maxLength" for the `textbox` tag

Answer (score 0):

[Doesn't look like there's any max length properties for that specific control by default.](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-8-html/allmembers_t_telerik_ui_radautocompletebox.html)

However, you should easily be able to manipulate the method that you're binding with the `Command` attribute to first check the textbox and make sure it doesn't exceed a certain number of characters.

If it does, stop execution of the command.  If it doesn't, then proceed.

Comment: But your suggestion will allow users to be able to key in more than allowable number of characters no?

Comment: If they do so, then stop execution and display an error message.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding?  Are you wanting to stop input entirely once they reach a certain number of chars?

Comment: Yeah, if i set it to 5 character, there is no way user can key in 6th characters

Comment: What about the `Change()` event listener?  Can you bind a validator to that?

Comment: Do you mind to show me some small piece of code as I'm very new to wpf area